# TailwindCSS: How do I make a responsive grid with different ratios?

Tags: css, css-grid, tailwind-css

I need your advice. I am working on a simple page design for displaying a product article. I am using TailwindCSS for this. (Tailwind is very cool tool!).
Here is my question: How do I make a responsive grid with different ratios?

For the breakpoint prefixes **sm** and **md** the page width should be **50%** to **50%**. But for the breakpoint prefix lg the aspect ratio should be **~30%** to **~70%**. And under the breakpoint **sm**, two lines are to be displayed.

Here is my current code. Thanks for your support!

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.15/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-blue-400 text-blue-400 min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 px-2">
    
    <div class="col-span-2 sm:col-span-1 bg-white p-5 rounded text-center">
      <img class="w-full object-cover object-center" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x666">
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-2 sm:col-span-1 bg-white p-10 rounded ">
      <h1 class="uppercase text-3xl">Title</h1>
      <h3 class="uppercase text-md">Subtitle</h3>      
      <div class="leading-10">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quia, quae. Exercitationem, aspernatur cupiditate reiciendis veniam fugiat rerum officia dolor accusantium ipsam cum provident eum voluptatum numquam consequatur! Consectetur, quos rem. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quia, quae. Exercitationem, aspernatur cupiditate reiciendis veniam fugiat rerum officia dolor accusantium ipsam cum provident eum voluptatum numquam consequatur! Consectetur, quos rem.

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-2 bg-white p-10 rounded">
        comments
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the Tailwind Play to edit it online:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/gPFDif7RKx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 10 column grid layout `grid-cols-10` instead of `grid-cols-2`.

**50% to 50%** --> `col-span-5` + `col-span-5`

**30% to 70%** --> `col-span-3` + `col-span-7`

**under the breakpoint sm** --> `grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-10`

Comment: Very cool and easy!   ```<div class="col-span-10 sm:col-span-5 lg:col-span-3 bg-white p-5 rounded text-center">Image</div><div class="col-span-10 sm:col-span-5 lg:col-span-7 bg-white p-10 rounded ">content</div>```